# Encoding filenames mismatch beetwen SQL and filesystem after transfer of script to new server

Tags: mysql, file, drupal, utf-8, mojibake

I have moved my Drupal site into new server. Unluckily now all my file links containing polish letters in names are broken.

I have looked threw the script/database/file system to find out what is wrong and found the following:

- Drupal shows the following error:

> /sites/default/files/Baranowska_Badania%20naukowe%20i%20testowanie%20nowych%20lek%C3%B3w%20na%20ludziach%20i%20zwierz%C4%99tach-aspekt%20prawny%20i%20etyczny_0.pdf

- The file exists on server and is accessible but under the following
  link:

> ```
>  http://ppes.mage.pl/sites/default/files/Baranowska_Badania%20naukowe%20i%20testowanie%20nowych%20lekow%20na%20ludziach%20i%20zwierzetach-aspekt%20prawny%20i%20etyczny_0.pdf
> ```

- In mysql the file link looks like this:

> ```
> public://Baranowska_Badania naukowe i testowanie nowych leków na ludziach i zwierzętach-aspekt prawny i etyczny_0.pdf
> ```

As you may see the problem is with link encoding. File names in SQL contain polish letters when real file names on linux system does not.

I would like to ask you whether there is any easy way to solve this out or the only way is to manually replace all polish chars in database with their respective non-polish equivalents (eg. "ę" => "e" ; "ó" => "o")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I executed the following queries:

```
     UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'ą́', 'a');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'ę', 'e');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'ż', 'z');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'ź', 'z');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'ó', 'o');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'ś', 's');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'ć', 'c');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'Ś', 'S');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'Ź', 'Z');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'Ż', 'Z');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'Ń', 'N');
     UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'ń', 'n');
     UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'Ł', 'L');
 UPDATE file_managed SET `filename` = REPLACE(`filename`, 'ł', 'l');

UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'Ł', 'L');
    UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'ł', 'l');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'ą́', 'a');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'ę', 'e');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'ż', 'z');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'ź', 'z');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'ó', 'o');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'ś', 's');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'ć', 'c');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'Ś', 'S');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'Ż', 'Z');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'Ź', 'Z');
    UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'Ń', 'N');
        UPDATE file_managed SET `uri` = REPLACE(`uri`, 'ń', 'n');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [Transliteration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) which will convert all filenames to US-ASCII.
2. Check database charset and collation at localhost and remote server. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html